# How to write a book title, subtitle, edition and author in a work email?

Tags: writing

I'm requesting that my organization upload a digital version of a book and I want to make sure they give me the correct one. I would like to include the following information in my request. Book title, subtitle, edition, and author. I'm uncertain about the order and the proper punctuation. This is not a scholarly citation, just a request of purchase, really? Here is the way I wrote it. Raise the Issue; An Integrated Approach to Critical Thinking, Third Edition by: Carol Numrich

Comment: Obviously not an answer related to English language usage, but just a tip for unambiguously identifying books: use the ISBN.  In this case, ISBN 0-201-62100-2.  Any library or bookseller should be able to find the book using that number.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't within this site's scope

Comment: @DialFrost No of course not. Writing has nothing to do with learning languages at. I've been professional English Teacher 7 years. Every Language Teaching methodology I've come across has said to avoid teaching writing.

Comment: @DialFrost Actually this is one of the questions my students asked me. I guess I should tell him I can't teach him that because it's not within this site's scope....

Comment: @Juhasz Same question to you. What shall I tell the ESL students who asked me this.question. Sorry it's not part of the English Language?

Comment: @DanielWard Hmm, did JamesK answer help you though?

Comment: What should you tell the student who asked this question?  You can tell them what James K wrote and/or recommend that they use an ISBN to unambiguously identify the book.  From your comments, it appears that you may be after some other, or additional information.  If that's the case, you might consider updating your original question to include a more specific request.

Comment: @Juhasz The answer I needed was precisely what James K wrote. But according to your first post this wasn't an appropriate question for the site. So, have you changed your mind on that issue, now that you know what I was asking for and why?

Comment: You've misread my comment.  I was providing you with something that was "not an answer related to English language usage, but just a tip."  Incidentally, if you think James's answer is correct, you should click the check mark on his answer to indicate such.

Comment: @Juhasz Oh, I'm sorry about that. I did misread your comment.Thank you for the advice on check mark. I didn't know that. I thought you were in the same line as DialFrost. Because I teach ESL I'm always asking questions on here for clarity. But for some reason every question I ask gets flagged as off topic. Do you know I might prevent that?

Comment: Personally, I don't think this question is off topic, but perhaps I can see why others would think so.  The way you've phrased the question, it looks like you're asking a very narrow question; something like, "how should I submit a purchase request at my office?"  And the answer to that narrow question might be: "It probably doesn't really matter; office managers don't have any expectations about book title formats."  We want questions and answers to be useful to a very broad audience.  A good question/answer should convey a general lesson.  That's why proof-reading questions are off-topic...

Comment: There's more to be said about this, but it really would be better to ask about why your questions are getting marked as off-topic on our meta site: https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/.  There's more room for discussion there.  And comments - especially these kinds of comments - are likely to be deleted.  So any answer I could provide here but be erased before you read it.

Comment: @Juhasz Thank you my friend you are a gentleman and a scholar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are writing a formal reference for publication there are strict style rules.  But for a generic request there are no special rules.

There are some guidelines.  The title and subtitle may be italicised, and you should use the same punctuation and capitalisation for the title and subtitle as on the title page A colon is normal.  The edition could be in parentheses.  You don't need any punctuation after the word "by".

It is more important to get the title right.  You have made a mistake... can you spot it?"

> *[Raise the Issues: An Integrated Approach to Critical Thinking](http://tesl-ej.org/wordpress/issues/volume8/ej30/ej30r1/)* (Third Edition) by Carol Numrich.

But don't overthink this. Your punctuation would get the job done fine.